# Can we write core Android apps and do a custom build?

Tags: android

I was looking at this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

The section about "Applicatiosn" says that android ships with "a set of core applications" and "All applications are written using the Java programming language".

1. Is it possible for me to write my own applications is whatever language the "core applications" are written in? (I assume that langauge is C).
2. Will doing so require me to do a custom build of android and install it on my device?
3. Are there any tutorials/documentations telling me how to do this?

Please lets not debate the disadvantages of this approach - I'm pretty sure there will be many, the first being the development time involved. The purpose of this exercising is to learn, not to build.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As the page you quoted states, the “core applications” are written using the Java programming language, although it’s possible that some of them are written in C using the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). In the [list of git repositories](http://android.git.kernel.org/) for the Android Open Source Project, scroll to the ones called `platform/packages`. Any one of these can be downloaded and compiled. I would not be surprised if some failed to build due to dependencies, but I think they are all self-contained with only SDK requirements.
2. System packages cannot be removed without root access, and can only be upgraded by packages signed with the correct key (for example, the Gmail, Maps, and YouTube apps available in the Market). Thus, if you create your own version of a system package, you will have to package it with a different name in the manifest for it to be installable.

   You can create your own build of Android with your own system packages, but this is overkill. If you just wish to replace a system app on your own device, and you have root access, you can *(carefully!)* back up and uninstall the system package, and then you will be free to install any version of the package without worrying about keys.
3. If “this” is just downloading and building one of the packages, the hardest part might be installing the Android SDK and using Eclipse, or it might be figuring out how to clone a git repository. If “this” is creating a custom build of Android, it’s beyond me. ;)

   The default branch in these repositories will be for 2.3. Make sure you install an Android SDK that’s compatible with your device, and check out the correct branch of the repository if necessary.

   For example, I cloned the `platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git` repository:

   ```
   $ git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git
   $ cd DeskClock
   ```

   Then I updated the build.xml file and tried building it (of course, you could import it into Eclipse instead):

   ```
   $ android update project -p . -t android-8
   $ ant debug
   [javac] /Users/josh/android/DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock/HandleSetAlarm.java:25: cannot find symbol
   [javac] symbol  : class AlarmClock
   [javac] location: package android.provider
   [javac] import static android.provider.AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM;
   ```

   Right, that’s for Gingerbread. Checking out Froyo...

   ```
   $ git checkout froyo
   $ ant debug
   ```

   Good, it worked, and I have an `apk` signed with a debug key.

   ```
   $ ant install
   [echo] Installing /Users/josh/android/DeskClock/bin/DeskClock-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
   [exec] 342 KB/s (400831 bytes in 1.143s)
   [exec]  pkg: /data/local/tmp/DeskClock-debug.apk
   [exec] Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
   ```

   So it doesn’t want to install a custom version of a system package. I modified `<manifest package="com.android.deskclock">` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and…well, it complained about `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED`. The rest is an exercise for the reader.